# SQL Developer with shared connections

Tags: share, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to ask you if possible to use one database of connections shared between multiple SQL Developer clients. I mean something line group of people can have their own SQL Developer client on the PC with one shared connections DB, so one add/change/delete the connection, everyone will notice that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using tnsnames.ora on your system. You can specify the tnsnames.ora location in Windows menu, Preferences, expand Database, and select Advance.

Here's more information on using tnsnames.ora file: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/tnsnames.htm

Hope it helps!